# codeigniter mail vs swiftmailer for bulk email

Tags: php, codeigniter, swiftmailer

i have an old system and a new one, which i'm developing:

in the old system i used crontab and swiftmailer to send a newsletter. i've written a PHP script that reads the mailing list from the database and sends emails to the entire list using swiftmailer+smtp with delays between each group of emails to make sure i'm not overloading the server (swift mailer has this under Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin).

also i've written another script that would scan the address i've sending from for incoming emails, find failure notifications etc and match addresses to clear the database from emails that are not active (ie if you send an email to an address that does not exist, you receive a mail with an error message, i fetched the address from the content and removed it from the database).

this method served over 40K emails on a daily basis. worked like a charm.

in the new system which i'm writing, i'm using code igniter. the built in mail feature for code igniter seems to do the work fine, only 1 thing is missing: is it possible to add delays between sends?

i know it's simple to add the swiftMailer library to my CI project, but before i do that, can this be done using CI mail func. alone? are there any other advantages for adding swift mailer in this case?

I know many people will advise using something which is built for bulk email, but PHP CLI is just like any other programming language in this case (i'm aware of mailman, majordomo, and services like mailchip. i can do multithreading in php with sysdaemons and mod_fork etc when needed, but that's irrelevant for the question).

EDIT:

**SOLVED**

even though i already added the swift mailer (which took a few minutes), [Sparks](http://getsparks.org/packages/PersonalizedMailer/versions/HEAD/show) suggested by @JaredFarrish seems to be the solution, since it's designed for CI.

Comment: Have you seen this? [Sparks PersonalizedMailer](http://getsparks.org/packages/PersonalizedMailer/versions/HEAD/show)

Comment: There's also [BCC Batch Mode, enabling large email lists to be broken into small BCC batches](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html).

Comment: nope, i haven't. i actually added swiftmailer already and written a small library for it. I'll replace it with sparks. thanks ;)

Comment: @JaredFarrish, does it allow sending different contents? i have to replace unsubscribe links etc for each email

Comment: It should. [Personalized emails including support for variable substitutions (e.g. `Hello [firstname] [lastname]`...)](https://github.com/joeauty/Personalized-Mailer-CodeIgniter-Spark#readme)

Comment: heh, i meant the BCC batch mode. i know Sparks handles it

Comment: Oh, I doubt it. Maybe, if you managed the send yourself, but that seems self-defeating.

Comment: If it is solved, you should close the question.

Comment: Package management in PHP is so much fun!

Comment: If it's solved maybe close the question and maybe add your solution as an answer? Could help people with a similar problem.

Comment: the solution is either use Sparks, or write your own library. it's in the post. The "Close" op requires me to select a reason, which doesn't include "question solved". Any way to mark the question as "solved" ?